# Load a Silverlight App from an ASPX loaded assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, plugins

We're using an MVC-based plugin architecture using ASPX pages (because Razor ones need to be precompilated). Thus we're using a custom AssemblyResourceProvider to get the custom streams for the pages.

The problem comes when we try to load a Silverlight Application on the ASPX page that's on the same assembly as the page, as an embedded resource (because we want a full plugin architecture, a single dll should be enough for everything). Even with using a physical .XAP we can't get it to work, we suppose that as the path of the page is virtual, it won't be able to search the file thus generating a 2104 silverlight error.

We can use a http uri to get the .xap, and it'll be out last resort, but we'd like to do something similar as creating a custom AssemblyResourceProvider for ASPX pages and getting the stream from the assembly.

Is that even possible?